# Swift get reference to a class in a different VC

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift

I have 2 different `UIViewControllers`, let's call them `ViewControllerA.swift` and `ViewControllerB.swift`. In my storyboard I created a `TabViewController` with 2 tabs, those 2 VC. Now when I load `ViewControllerB` I would like to get some data stored in `ViewControllerA` variables, but how could i get the reference to `ViewControllerA` class?

I **know** that using this code

```
var vcA : ViewControllerA = ViewControllerA()
```

I'm creating a new instance of `ViewControllerA`, and it's **not** what i want. There is also `no segue`, in that case I could have passed the reference through `prepareForSegue`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: first of all... the _view_ or _controller_ layers are not for storing data – for that there is the _model_ layer which you have to implement properly, perhaps, if you have not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBarController` has a property `viewControllers`. You can access the tabBarViewController in your viewController like this:

**Update:**

```
// viewControllers contains ViewControllerB instance itself and ViewControllerA instance
// say you have vcA and  vcB

// contains vcA
vcB.tabBarController.viewControllers[0]

// contains vcB
vcB.tabBarController.viewControllers[1]
```

You can also say:

```
// contains vcA
vcA.tabBarController.viewControllers[0]

// contains vcB
vcA.tabBarController.viewControllers[1]
```

Comment: How do i access `ViewControllerA` from viewControllers array? something like `viewControllers[0]`?

Comment: Yes, depends on the order of ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB.

Comment: In your code `ViewControllerB` in the instance of itself? I can only access tabBarController with `ViewControllerB()`, how could i get the current reference of itself?

Comment: In `ViewControllerB` i'm using this `var vc:ViewControllerA = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as ViewControllerA` but it crashes saying that was found nil while unwrapping. Isn't it the kind of code you suggested?